# How to send a GUID to a web api webservice

Tags: asp.net-web-api, guid

I am extending `ApiController` for a webservice.

The service takes a GUID as its only parameter.  This is the url that I type in

```
/api/texts/2ADEA345-7F7A-4313-87AE-F05E8B2DE678
```

However, the Guid never reaches the `Get` method.

**If I set it to object**

```
public Object Get(Object userId)
```

the method fires, but userid is null.

**If i set it to guid**

```
public Object Get(Guid? userId)
```

I get the error

> No action was found on the controller 'texts' that matches the request.

Does anyone have a sample that could help me?

Comment: Did you tried a string as parameter?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I suppose that you are using the default route in which the pattern is:

```
api/{controller}/{id}
```

So try naming your parameter accordingly:

```
public TextsController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid? id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now the `/api/texts/2ADEA345-7F7A-4313-87AE-F05E8B2DE678` url should hit the `Get` action on the `TextsController` and populate the `id` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @darin-dimitrov for the neat answer. But I have a question, Is it a right approach to pass GUID for RESTful service? I am intended to use GUID in my GET service. But it has 32 characters length, apart from that, does it violates any semantic meaning or any design patterns?

Comment: I don't think so and you can use it comfortably @Pandiarajan. Actually, using GUID or an integer id is depending what retrieving you are. I mean according from more important to less important data.

Comment: @AbdurrahmanI. This Guid represents correlation id of the communication. Generated by the consumer of the WebApi, to ensure idempotency.